# Indexing list elements from another list

Tags: r, indexing

I have a problem, I have two lists.
Each of these has stored 3 vectors of identical length.
The only difference is that in list_A I have numeric values and in list_B I have logical values.
I want to extract the index of the true values in the logical vector from list_B and use their index for extracting values from list_A.

```
listA <- list(c(14,6,4,6,14,5,14,13,4,6,14,14,3,10,14,13,6),c(16,3,8,16,11,5,4,16,17,15,16,10),c(11,5,6,3,5,4,6,13,14,5,5,14,14,13,6,9))

listB <- list(c("FALSE","FALSE","FALSE" ,"FALSE" ,"FALSE" ,"FALSE", "FALSE" ,"FALSE" ,"FALSE" ,"FALSE" ,"FALSE" ,"FALSE" ,"FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE"),
              c("FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE",  "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE"),
              c("FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE",  "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE"))

IDs <- lapply(listB, function(x) which(x==T))

# Which command could I use to extract the numeric value from listA for TRUE cases?
```

Could someone help me?
Nadine

Comment: Hi there! Don't forget to add the tag R to your questions, it will be easier to find by the R experts ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can actually use the logical vectors directly without needing to extract the indices, for example:

```r
my_vec <- c(2, 5, 12, 8, 0, 90)
my_vec[c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)]
```

But the main issue in the example you provided is that `listB` is not really logical (boolean), the elements there are of type character because you used the quotes around them, so if your original data is of type character you need to convert it to logical or use `=="TRUE"`

And since this can only be done with vectros (and not lists) and you already have two lists to loop through I would use `mapply` so basically:

```r
mapply(function(vec1, vec2) vec2[vec1=="TRUE"], listB, listA)
```

or

```r
mapply(function(vec1, vec2) vec2[as.logical(vec1)], listB, listA)
```